# GSI Instantiation Failed in Couchbase

Tags: couchbase, couchbase-view, sql++

When I try to implement my N1Ql query which uses GSI in the log it says

GSI instantiation failed: Post /_metakv: missing port in address

I have tried gooling it, but the basic result that I get is issue: MB-15001

For Example:
When I fire the Query:
CREATE INDEX ko ON beer-sample(name);
Result is:

```
{
"requestID": "63ba3eae-528c-4042-a8ba-807a7096144d",
"signature": null,
"results": [
],
"status": "success",
"metrics": {
"elapsedTime": "6.092730473s",
"executionTime": "6.092483222s",
"resultCount": 0,
"resultSize": 0
}
}
```

But when I fire the same Query Using GSI i.e.

CREATE INDEX new ON beer-sample(name) USING GSI ;

Result:

```
{
"requestID": "a864c2a7-475d-4794-b267-cca89efb9b9e",
"signature": null,
"results": [
],
"errors": [
{
"code": 12005,
"msg": "Indexer not implemented GSI may not be enabled"
}
],
"status": "errors",
"metrics": {
"elapsedTime": "1.194775ms",
"executionTime": "1.008475ms",
"resultCount": 0,
"resultSize": 0,
"errorCount": 1
}
}
```

In the Logger:

```
time=2015-07-22T12:07:18+05:30 level=ERROR _msg=GSIC[default; beer-sample] GSI instantiation failed: Post /metakv: missing port in address
time=2015-07-22T12:07:18+05:30 _level=WARN _msg=Error loading GSI indexes for keyspace beer-sample. Error GSI client instantiation failed - cause: Post /metakv: missing port in address
```

Please provide a detailed solution.

Comment: what version of Couchbase Server are you using? Is it 4.0 BETA? If so, did you check "indexer" on at least one node in your cluster when installing? (in the webconsole, server nodes, at least one node should show "query" and "index" in the services column)

Comment: Yeah I am using Couchbase 4.0 . And I am performing it on a single node and I have checked all the three operations when installing it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what OS you are using but if it is `Amazon Linux` be sure to run

```
yum install openssl098e
```

before installing `couchbase`.  I had the same issue and since installing `openssl098e` everything has been working great.